# How do I order an array of Doctrine objects?

Tags: php, doctrine

I have:

```
return $this->BuildElement;
```

Where *$this* corresponds to object representing the parent table (Build) of BuildElement. Build has many BuildElements so the above code returns an array of BuildElement objects, however I want to order them according to the values of certain columns but don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

if you need to return a list of BuildElements identified by parent id ordered bycriteria, you would propably do this using DQL, something like this:

`Doctrine_Query::create()->from('BuildElement be')->innerJoin('be.Build b')->where('b.id = ?', $parendId)->orderBy('be.yourColumn ASC')->execute();`

You can see this in Doctrine docs: [Doctrine DQL manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#select-queries)

Also, depends whether you're using Doctrine 1.x or 2.x

Comment: Thanks Thomas, initially that is what I did, but it wasn't returning objects I expected it to. I discovered later on there was problem with my DQL statement.